# Does .net framework provides image processing library?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some images in png format, I am wondering whether there are .net library to process images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at GDI+ ([System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace) or [WIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component), both have managed wrappers built into the .NET framework. For example here's an [interesting article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx) comparing both methods for resizing an image. Of course depending on your specific requirements and what exactly do you mean by *processing images* there might be also third party libraries.

Comment: I know that working images in c# very ineffective(performance wise), you should use C++ for that purposes.

Comment: @IamStalker, *processing images* is very broad term. Let's not precipitate to make make general conclusions without narrowing down the scenario. Once we have a very specific task we could start writing sample code and measuring the performance and have exact figures, just like the author of article I have linked to does to compare GDI+ and WIC.

Comment: i think you right, but on my experience i had using C# to create and rebuild images, C# is not the best tool there is.

Comment: Acutally perforamnce is quite ok if you are not stupid enough to use arrays (some stuff are better done with pointers which you CAN have in C#). And then for some things the graphics card rules - load the image on a direct3x surface, run code on the graphics card.

Comment: How to load image on a direct3x surface?

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class supports BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG, and TIFF. You can at least display your PNGs using that.

Also I found a library [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)  which is used in an [image processing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9727/Image-Processing-Lab-in-C) on codeplex.